# Pre-processing on multiple CPUs in parallel and feeding output to tensorflow which trains on Multi-GPUs

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, tensorflow

I am trying to use Tensorflow for my work on a classification problem.

Before feeding the input in the form of images, I want to do some pre-processing on the images. I would like to carry out this pre-processing on multiple CPU cores in parallel and feed them to the TensorFlow graph which I want to run in a Multi-GPU setting (I have 2 TitanX GPUs).

The reasoning I want this setup is, so that while the GPU is performing the training, the CPUs keep on doing their job of pre-processing and hence after each iteration, the GPU does not remain idle. I have been looking into the TensorFlow API for this, but could not locate something which specifically addresses such a scenario.

So, multiple CPU cores should keep on pre-processing a list of files and fill in a queue from which TensorFlow extracts its batch of data. Whenever this queue is full, CPU cores should wait and again start processing when the queue (or part of it) is vacated due to feeding of examples to TensorFlow graph.

I have two questions specifically :

- How may I achieve this setup ?
- Is it a good idea to have this setup ?

A clear example would be a great help.

Comment: The inception model provided by google in the tensorflow/models repository does exactly this.

Comment: Does it ? Taking a deeper look now.

Comment: It seems this is it :)